# AspectJ - pointcut with dynamic value

Tags: aspectj

Is it possible doing something like this?

```
private static final String PACKAGE = System.getProperty("packagePrefix", "org.company_name");

@Around("execution(* "+PACKAGE+"..*.*(..)) && @annotation(validate)")
```

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  This is not possible since the compiler/weaver must know exactly what will be woven at compile time. Using compile time weaving, pointcuts may not change across restarts of the application.